# How to send a parameter to JSP whice is inside TIles definition

Tags: jsp, struts, tiles

Tiles.xml

```
<definition name="keycontacts" extends="MainPage" > 
<put-attribute name="title" value="Contacts" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/displayContacts.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="keyContacts">
<result name="success" type="tiles" >keycontacts</result>
</action>
```

displayContacts.jsp page takes a parameter "ID" based on which it fetches result from the DataBase. if i dont use the tiles and directly call the displayContacts.jsp in my STRUTS.XML then it is working fine, but when i use tiles then `"The requested resource is not available."` error appears.

my question is : How can we send a param to a jsp which is being used inside Tiles definition?

please provide me the example code.

Comment: `<put-attribute name="title" value="Contacts" />` doesn't resolve to a JSP, might be the cause of error.

Comment: secondly, I see `<action name="keyContacts">` not mapped to any action-class. I wonder how & where do you fetch result from database when the action is not mapped to any class.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special to pages in tiles-definitions. They are just like any other jsp page.

You can have a getter & setter for a variable in the action and then that variable is accessible in the JSP.

**MyAction.java**

```
private String name;

public String getName(){ return name; }
```

**MyJsp.jsp**

```
<s:property value="name"/>
```

If it's a request parameter you can directly access via the parameters map in jsp.

```
<s:property value="#parameters['name']"/>
```